# What requirements on type used in IEnumerable.GroupBy()?

Tags: c#, linq

I was using `GroupBy` with an anonymous type:

```
var v = list.GroupBy(x => new {x.street, x.houseNumber});
var o = v.Single(x => x.Key.street == "My Street" && x.Key.houseNumber == 42);
```

It worked great. I decided to turn this into a concrete type:

```
class StreetAddress
{
 public StreetAddress(string _street,int _houseNumber){...}
 public string street{get; set;}
 public int houseNumber{get;set;}
}
var v = list.GroupBy(x => new StreetAddress(x.street, x.houseNumber));
var o = v.Single(x => x.Key == new StreetAddress("My Street", 42));
```

Now 'v' is not grouped at all - loads of items with the same `Key` value, and `o` doesn't match any objects.

What do I need to add to `StreetAddress` so this works as it did with an anonymous type?

Comment: Show us how list is defined.It might have something to do with the fact that you're using refererence types to check for equality. Try making  the StreetAddress a struct.

Comment: `list` is the result of another LINQ call on a collection of objects which have the 2 properties mentioned, all very normal. Interesting idea about using a struct though, you get memberwise comparison automatically then? For this simple case that might be easier.

Comment: To make a simple linq statement you can have the class StreetAddress inherit IComparable and include a CompareTo() method.

Comment: (As an aside, you should definitely start following .NET naming conventions - PascalCase property names, and no underscore prefix on parameter names.)

Answer (score 7):

> What do I need to add to StreetAddress so this works as it did with an anonymous type?

Override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, basically. Ideally, implement `IEquatable<StreetAddress>`, but mostly for the sake of clarity.

Your query currently *is* grouped by the only type of equality that the type expresses - referential equality. But as you're creating a new instance for each item, no two keys will ever be equal to each other.

Comment: I see alternative discussion about implementing `IComparable`. I am going to take a wild leap and assume your answer is the correct one but could you touch on that? Is it wrong, not as good, etc?

Comment: @Mr.Boy: Yes, it's wrong. Grouping is about finding *equal* values, not ordering values.

Comment: Doesn't CompareTo() Produce Equal when zero is returned?

Comment: @jdweng: Usually - but `GroupBy` simply doesn't use `CompareTo`, because it's *only* interested in equality.

Answer (score -2):

Here is how to implement IComparable

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication93
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var v = StreetAddress.addresses.GroupBy(x => x);
        }
    }
    class StreetAddress : IComparable
    {
        public static List<StreetAddress> addresses { get; set; }
        public string street { get; set; }
        public int houseNumber { get; set; }

        public StreetAddress() { ; }
        public StreetAddress(string _street, int _houseNumber)
        {
            StreetAddress newAddress = new StreetAddress();
            addresses.Add(newAddress);
            newAddress.street = _street;
            newAddress.houseNumber = _houseNumber;
        }
        public int CompareTo(object _other)
        {
            int results = 0;
            StreetAddress other = (StreetAddress)_other;
            if (this.street != other.street)
            {
                results = this.street.CompareTo(other.street);
            }
            else
            {
                results = this.houseNumber.CompareTo(other.houseNumber);
            }

            return results;
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: `IComparable` is for ordering, not grouping - grouping uses equality comparisons.